# How do I upgrade to a new version of Android?

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the OS on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-on-my-device)

So, I got an ePad AKA zenithink zt 180 (I know, I know it's cheap and I should have got a better piece of hardware, but i was too eager to get a tablet and this one was affordable)

It has 2.1 on it and I want to upgrade to 2.2 (for adobe flash).

The copy of Android looks like they just took the developer edition (i see a dev tools app pre-installed... not sure) and slapped it on there with no customization.

So, can you guys help me with step-by-step instructions on how to upgrade and where to find the latest copy?

I have a developer account already if that helps...

I would appreciate any help as I'm afraid of bricking it. There's no way to automatically update this thing either (that i can find) :-/

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a version that is specifically designed for your device that has all the drivers necessary to operate your specific hardware configuration.  If no one has compiled a ROM for it you'd have to build one yourself from scratch.  You best bet finding a 2.2 ROM for you device is over at the [XDA Developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/).  Then even if you're able to load 2.2, Flash is going to be a whole different story.  I had the Viewsonic g-tablet with Froyo (which as a Tegra2 Processor) but the Flash that I side-loaded wouldn't work at all.  Force close after force close.  Then with my newest tab, the Archos 70, even after they released 2.2 it was a while before anyone could find a version of Flash that would run without force closing and it still operates poorly.  I suspect you're going to be disappointed with your Flash experience, especially if you have cheap hardware.

Comment: You're confirming my suspicions. I found a forum for this tablet that directed me to the packages, but the compiled kernel (etc...) were on a site that was in Chinese. I'm afraid I'm going to turn this sucker into a brick if I try and load that stuff. I guess it's safer to stick with no flash and 2.1 :(

Comment: if you are just looking to watch flash video on the web, Skyfire is a good alternative to Flash.  It doesn't work on every site, but I had good luck with it.

Comment: and that works on 2.1? I would like to watch hulu...

Comment: I would too but Hulu blocks Skyfire :o(  It does work on 2.1 though, just not Hulu.

Comment: Yep just figured that out :( Hulu appears to blocking every mobile browser. I have 2.2 on my Droid X and Flash installed and hulu still says you need flash to watch these movies... I wonder whats up with that...

Comment: Probably licencing agreements with the studios. I wish theyd hurry up and port their iOS app to android.