# what is reason behind android update application

Tags: applications

What things responsible for android update. . Means if i have a android phone which will not upgrade my os version .
In this scenario , why it is not upgradable ?.. what factor make it .? 
Any hardware problem or 
any other ?

Comment: Recommended reading: Our [update tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/update/info). It contains links to posts dealing with stuff around "how to update", etc. For a short answer: If your manufacturer doesn't offer an update, there will be no "official update". Especially see: [Can every Android device be updated to the most recent Android version?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14267/16575)

Answer (score 1):

One of those reasons:

1. Manufacturer of your phone is too lazy to issue updated compatible ROM with your phone.
2. Your phone has old hardware that may not work with new android versions, or it's very hard to modify it to become compatible.
3. You played with your original ROM, that is some companies checks if you are rooted, or if you reflashed new ROMs on your phone, and consider it as you don't deserve to update your phone :D

Comment: While #2 is often mentioned by manufacturers, it's rarely true – as the community proves often enough. My oldest device (HTC Wildfire/Buzz from 2010) is currently running ICS thanks to CM, my Milestone² can be updated to Kitkat thanks to CM – just to mention 2 examples. But building updated ROMs doesn't bring in additional money plus, thanks to "specific GUI modifications" (Blur, Sense, YouNameIt) is not that easy.